# Linux server with Samba 4 as DC, filserver and netatalk (AFP for OS X)

Tags: samba4, netatalk

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server with samba 4.0.6 and netatalk 3.0.4. Samba is DC and fileserver. All with ACL and ext4 with acl filesystem. I managed to get the ubuntu server to join the domain with centrifydc trough changing the hostname in /etc/hostname

Seems like ACL is complicated in an mixed environment. I have therefore not got it to work as it should (OS X with AFP don't read ACL as windows and don't get write permissions to files and folders).

I guess the easiest solution would be to just skip ACL and use unix filegroups. But how do I do that on samba 4?

I have removed acl (from linux terminal) and got AFP connections to work as I will, but then I dont' get access with smb (seems like samba 4 just recognizes ACL?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try whether "map acls = mode" in afp.conf helps with AFP permissions when dealing with ACLS.

Comment: Thanks! Not found time to try it yet, but I will. Unfortunately limited functionality of winbind 4 keeps us from using AFP on same server as samba 4.

Comment: Did this. Also I will mention that the ugly "hack" to get join AD with Centirfy DC broke after some days. I'm now using winbind 4 (http://serverfault.com/questions/527332/ubuntu-12-04-samba-4-and-winbind), and it seems like it is all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Samba3 for the file server and use Samba4 only as an AD DC?

Comment: On same server? I've found out that winbind 4 has limited functionality, so probably the best solution would have been to have 2 servers. In this case we probably will be stuck with smb until winbind 4 gets better.

Comment: I think having 2 servers may make life a little easier for you.