# Ubuntu 12.04 Samba 4 and winbind

Tags: samba4

I've been following: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba4/Winbind but getent passwd dosn't show domain users, and I cannot login with domain users. The rest of the test commands are OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do the following:

Install: libpam0g-dev with:

```
# apt-get install libpam0g-dev
```

and then recompile and reinstall samba 4 from source.

in stead of the winbind 4 wiki:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/samba/lib/libnss_winbind.so.2 /lib/libnss_winbind.so
# ln -s libnss_winbind.so /lib/libnss_winbind.so.2
```

I used:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/samba/lib/libnss_winbind.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# ln -s /usr/local/samba/lib/libnss_winbind.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

In stead of the wiki:

```
# ln -s /usr/local/samba/lib/security/pam_winbind.so /lib/security
```

I used:

```
ln -s /usr/local/samba/lib/security/pam_winbind.so /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/
```

In /etc/pam.d/common-session i only put:

```
session required pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0022 skel=/etc/skel
```

in the beginning of the file. (Following the wiki on this file I got locked out also for local root user)